# how is a network analysis of a cloud different from a normal network analysis?

Tags: networking, cloud

If I want to check the number of packets transferred, analyze the traffic, detect intrusions or perform any other form of analysis, will it differ if the network is a cloud network?

I can't seem to understand the difference. There are so many papers on Intrusion detection in the cloud. How are they different from intrusion detection on a normal network.

Comment: Please define "cloud network"  because the word "Cloud" is a buzz word taht can mean a lot of things

Comment: @Nettogrof I mean a network in the cloud consisting of the nodes, controller and virtual instances. I am not trying to spam. I can't seem to understand the difference. There are so many papers on Intrusion detection in the cloud. How are they different from intrusion detection on a normal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree to previous point. According to me, there is no difference in cloud network or normal network. The networking protocols used are same and behave the same way. As protocols used are same for normal network and cloud network so network analysis should not differ.

However, if you are looking for packets flowing through a VM then you might like to gather statistics for packet flow in a server vs. packet flow in each VM of that server and compare them.

Cloud and virtualization goes hand in hand. As far as I know, there is no virtualization in network except in openflow which is a protocol proposed by Stanford University.

Answer (score 2):

NO DIFFERENCE.

Nettogrof is right! When people say "I don't keep it in local storage, I have it in the cloud", that just means that they uploaded it to some server. Companies started talking about "the cloud" recently just to sell the concept, and make it more abstract, as a way of saying "*I don't really care where the server is or if it's just one or several*", but the basic principle has been around for decades.

Answer (score 1):

there should be a difference since the level of abstraction of data flow is different. in cloud based you lose control of your data flow once it exits your local network, so you can only monitor the aggregate data flow between your local network and the gateway to your cloud server.
while in the later case you will get a more closer look at the movement of all your packets and get a detailed result.

While in the traditional 'normal' network intrusion detection usually means attacks trespassing your border ( you against the outer world) and corresponding privention methods are firewalls.
on the other hand the concept of intrusion changes to border-less security and usual security measures do not apply directly. and you have already mitigated the risk of border-wise intrusions, which you would prevent using firewalls, to a third party.